# Smaller "Turn off all sounds" widget

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, app-widgets

My OS version is 4.1.2.

I'm currently using the "Turn off all sound" 2x1 widget on my home screen, but I feel it is too big. I'm looking for a widget that is 1x1 and has the same functionality: mute all (or as many as possible) sounds and leaves vibration notifications on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Elixir 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bartat.android.elixir&hl=en). It lets you add different kinds of toggle widgets, including mute widgets.